# Solving Partial Differential Equation in 2D

Tags: partial-differential-equations, problem-solving

I have a heat equation to be solved for in the form of
$$u_{t}= u_{xx}+u_{yy} $$
for t = [0,+inf) and $0<x<1 ,0<y<1  $ and $u=u(x,y,t)$
and following B.C:
$$
u(0,0,t)=0
$$
$$
u(1,1,t)=1
$$
I work out the solution roughly using the following procedure:

1. $u(x,y,t)=f(\xi,\eta)$, with $\xi = \frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}$ and $\eta = \frac{y}{\sqrt{t}}$

   Obtain PDE as:
   $$
   -\frac{1}{2}(\xi f_\xi+\eta f_\eta)=f_{\xi\xi}+f_{\eta\eta}
   $$
   So, my question is

What is the appropriate way to solve this PDE ?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Welcome to math stackexchange! I'm wondering if this problem is even well-posed, since you are only specifying u at two points of the boundary square.

Answer (score 1):

This problem isn't well posed. Two non-identical solutions can be identified as: 
$$u_1(t,x,y) = x \ \ \ \ \ \ u_2(t,x,y) = y$$

Notice that each solution satisfies defining PDE and the boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and interest , If we take two identical solutions, what is the way to find the exact solution?

Comment: If you’re speaking of superposition, you can’t because the boundary conditions are not homogenous

Comment: Also, there is no exact solution. I just showed there’s more than one.